# What is the most efficient way to clip a video running through canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, html5-video

I have a situation where I need to clip either images or videos. The images or videos need to be able to overlap. We tried this originally with SVG, but for various reasons, that didn't work out well, so now we're doing it in Canvas.

This worked out fine for images, but when it comes to videos, the browser is brought almost to a screeching halt after about 2 minutes. ( What you won't see from the sample code or link is that we are also pausing the video while it's not in view, and while the tab isn't in view. )

Here is a link: http://codepen.io/paceaux/pen/egLOeR

Of chief concern is this method:

```
drawFrame () {
    if (this.isVideo && this.media.paused) return false;

    let x = 0;
    let width = this.media.offsetWidth;
    let y = 0;

    this.imageFrames[this.module.dataset.imageFrame](this.backContext);
    this.backContext.drawImage(this.media, x, y, width, this.canvas.height);

    this.context.drawImage(this.backCanvas, 0, 0);

    if (this.isVideo) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
            this.drawFrame();
        });
    }
}
```

You will observe the browser immediately slowing down. I don't recommend looking at that codepen for too terribly long because things everywhere will get awfully slow.

I'm using the ["backCanvas" technique](http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/) but that just seems to make things worse.

I've also tried to use `Path2D()` for saving the clip path, but that doesn't seem to help much, either.

```
        wedgeTop: (context, wedgeHeight = defaults.wedgeHeight) => {
        var wedge = new Path2D();

        wedge.moveTo(this.dimensions.width, 0);
        wedge.lineTo(this.dimensions.width, this.dimensions.height);
        wedge.lineTo(0, this.dimensions.height);
        wedge.lineTo(0, wedgeHeight);
        wedge.closePath();
        context.clip(wedge);
    },
```

Are there any other optimizations that I'm missing?  (save for the size of the video).

```js
let imageFrames =  function () {
 let defaults = {
  wedgeHeight: 50
 };
 return {
  defaults: defaults,

  //all wedges draw paths clockwise: top right, bottom right, bottom left, top left
  wedgeTop: (context, wedgeHeight = defaults.wedgeHeight) => {
   var wedge = new Path2D();

   wedge.moveTo(this.dimensions.width, 0);
   wedge.lineTo(this.dimensions.width, this.dimensions.height);
   wedge.lineTo(0, this.dimensions.height);
   wedge.lineTo(0, wedgeHeight);
   wedge.closePath();
   context.clip(wedge);
  },

  wedgeTopReverse: (context, wedgeHeight = defaults.wedgeHeight) => {
   var wedge = new Path2D();

   wedge.moveTo(this.dimensions.width, wedgeHeight);
   wedge.lineTo(this.dimensions.width, this.dimensions.height);
   wedge.lineTo(0, this.dimensions.height);
   wedge.lineTo(0, 0);
   wedge.closePath();
   context.clip(wedge);

  },

  wedgeBottom: (context, wedgeHeight = defaults.wedgeHeight) => {
   var wedge = new Path2D();

   wedge.moveTo(this.dimensions.width, 0);
   wedge.lineTo(this.dimensions.width, this.dimensions.height - wedgeHeight);
   wedge.lineTo(0, this.dimensions.height);
   wedge.lineTo(0,0);
   wedge.closePath();
   context.clip(wedge);
  },

  wedgeBottomReverse: (context, wedgeHeight = defaults.wedgeHeight) => {
   var wedge = new Path2D();

   wedge.moveTo(this.dimensions.width, 0);
   wedge.lineTo(this.dimensions.width, this.dimensions.height);
   wedge.lineto(0, this.dimensions.height - wedgeHeight);
   wedge.lineTo(0, 0);
   wedge.closePath();
   context.clip(wedge);
  }
 };
};

class ImageCanvasModule  {
 constructor(module) {
  this.module = module;
  this.imageFrames = imageFrames.call(this);

  if(this.isVideo) {
   /*drawFrame has a check where it'll only draw on reqAnimationFrame if video.paused === false,
   so we need to fire drawFrame on both events because that boolean will be false when it's paused, thus cancelling the animation frame
   */
   this.media.addEventListener('play', ()=>{
    this.drawOnCanvas();
   });

   this.media.addEventListener('pause', ()=> {
    this.drawOnCanvas();
   });
  }
 }

 get isPicture() {
  return (this.module.nodeName === 'PICTURE');
 }

 get isVideo() {
  return (this.module.nodeName === 'VIDEO');
 }

 get media() {
  return this.isPicture ? this.module.querySelector('img') : this.module;
 }

 get context() {
  return this.canvas.getContext('2d');
 }

 get dimensions() {
  return {
   width: this.module.offsetWidth,
   height: this.module.offsetHeight
  };
 }

 createCanvas () {
  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

  this.module.parentNode.insertBefore(canvas, this.module.nextSibling);
  canvas.className = this.module.className;

  this.canvas = canvas;

  this.createBackContext();
 }

 createBackContext () {
  this.backCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  this.backContext = this.backCanvas.getContext('2d');

  this.backCanvas.width = this.dimensions.width;
  this.backCanvas.height = this.backCanvas.height;
 }

 sizeCanvas () {
  this.canvas.height = this.dimensions.height;
  this.canvas.width = this.dimensions.width;

  this.backCanvas.height = this.dimensions.height;
  this.backCanvas.width = this.dimensions.width;
 }

 drawFrame () {
  if (this.isVideo && this.media.paused) return false;

  let x = 0;
  let width = this.media.offsetWidth;
  let y = 0;
  
  this.imageFrames[this.module.dataset.imageFrame](this.backContext);
  this.backContext.drawImage(this.media, x, y, width, this.canvas.height);

  this.context.drawImage(this.backCanvas, 0, 0);

  if (this.isVideo) {
   window.requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
    this.drawFrame();
   });
  }
 }

 drawOnCanvas () {
  this.sizeCanvas();
  this.drawFrame();
 }

 hideOriginal () {
  //don't use display: none .... you can't get image dimensions when you do that.
  this.module.style.opacity = 0;
 }
}
console.clear();

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=> {
 var els = document.querySelectorAll('.canvasify');
 var canvasified = [];

 for (el of els) {
  if (el.dataset.imageFrame) {
   let imageModule = new ImageCanvasModule(el);
   imageModule.createCanvas();
   imageModule.drawOnCanvas();
   imageModule.hideOriginal();
   canvasified.push(imageModule);
  }

 }
 console.log(canvasified);
});
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #333;
}

.container {
 height: 600px;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
}
.container + .container {
 margin-top: -150px;
}
.canvasify {
 position:absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: -1;
}
video {
 width: 100%
}

h1 {
 font-size: 2em;
 color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <img class="canvasify" data-image-frame="wedgeTop" src="http://placekitten.com/1280/500" />
 <h1>Kitty with a clipped top</h1>
</div>


<div class="container">
<video controls muted class="canvasify" loop autoplay data-image-frame="wedgeTop">
 <source src="https://poc5.ssl.cdn.sdlmedia.com/web/635663565028367012PU.mp4">
</video>
 <h1>video with a clipped top that overlaps the image above</h1>
</div>
```

The issue is that the codepen (and other pages running this code) are extremely slow. What optimizations am I missing, or using incorrectly?

[image: The desired effect is an image in one container, a video in another, and they're both cropped]

Comment: What do you mean by "overlaps"? Not certain what issue is?

Comment: The issue is that the page runs extremely slow. "Overlaps" means that the image from the video should be clipped, and overlap the image that sits above it. making it look like the video/image isn't rectangular, but cut out at angles.

Comment: Still no. I'm looking for exactly what you see in the codepen. Two separate containers. one might contain an image. Another might contain a video. Each container will have either video or image, and will be "clipped" at an angle. Text like from HTML, will sit over the image/video. So the bottom edge of an image in one container will visually display underneath a top edge of what might be a video. 

I don't need help with how to do it (I've already done it, and it works) I need help getting the page to perform better.

Comment: ok... just checking   o_o  (did the example code I linked to produce lag too?)

Comment: _"I need help getting the page to perform better."_ If only an image and a video are rendered why are `canvas` and  `requestAnimationFrame` necessary? How is performance currently measured?

Comment: @K3N your page didn't have any lag. which was amazing. I'm definitely sure I'm doing something wrong. just not sure what.

Comment: @guest271314 Right now I'm not "measuring". When I apply the code you see on a real page, scrolling and other on page animations lag when the video is in view. Also, Chrome's Task manager window starts showing that the tab is consuming a lot of memory and CPU when the video is in view.

Canvas is being used because we had too many cross-browser issues when trying to use SVG for this technique.

Comment: Why are `canvas` and calls to `requestAnimationFrame` necessary? You can use `video` and `img` elements, `css` to render same effect?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm not sure if I understand your question. We're doing this through canvas because attempts to use CSS and SVG to "clip" the media didn't work consistently in all browsers.

requesAnimationFrame is there to keep the video running through Canvas. Isn't that what you're supposed to do to run a video through Canvas? or is that what I'm missing?

Comment: The video and image do not render the same as image at Question at chromium. can you include `css` attempts at Question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135332/discussion-between-paceaux-and-guest271314).

Comment: @K3N Your examples still perform substantially better than mine. The page doesn't lag and all around get slower. I'm trying to figure out what we're doing different. What I observe is that you're doing the "cropping" outside of the loop that gets called in animation frame. I wonder if maybe that is my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comparing my code to how other people's code worked in this situation, I discovered that the flaw was in my `drawFrame()` method that I was using to actually draw the image from video into canvas.

There were two fundamental problems:

1. requestAnimationFrame() runs about 60fps, and because this is video, no more than 30 is needed
2. I was drawing the clipping in every instance of `drawFrame`, and I didn't need to do that. You can clip the canvas *once* and then run `requestAnimationFrame`

So, the new drawFrame method looks like this

```
    drawFrame () {
    if (this.isVideo && this.media.paused) return false;
    this.imageFrames[this.module.dataset.imageFrame]();

    var _this = this;
    var toggle = false;

    (function loop() {
        toggle= !toggle;

        if (toggle) {
            let x = 0;
            let width = _this.media.offsetWidth;
            let y = 0;

        _this.context.drawImage(_this.media, 0, 0, width, _this.canvas.height);
        }

        if (_this.isVideo) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        }

    })();
}
```

Issue 1 is resolved by using the `toggle` variable to only draw an image every other time the loop runs.

Issue 2 is resolved by cropping the image outside of the loop.

These two changes made a noticeable difference in how other elements on the page load, animate and respond to the user.

It seems obvious now, but clipping every single frame in a video is substantially more costly than clipping the *canvas*.

A big thanks goes to the user K3N whose code examples helped me find out the problem.